# Set font family and color in png plot device

Tags: r, plot, fonts, png

I'm plotting to a `png` device using `base` R. I want to force the font family to Calibri, with a specific shade of grey. I set the plot parameters in `par`.

When I plot interactively in RStudio, everything works fine, but not when I save to `png`. What's wrong here?

```
# set plot parameters
myfont <- 'Calibri'
mycol <- '#4B4B4D'
par(family = myfont, fg = mycol, col = mycol, col.axis = mycol, col.lab = mycol, col.main = mycol, col.sub = mycol)

# plot to default device works fine 
plot(x = c(1:10), y = rep(1, 10)) 

# export to png
png('d:/working/example.png', units = "in", width = 16, height = 9,
    pointsize = 12, res = 300, family = myfont)

plot(x = c(1:10), y = rep(1, 10)) # nope, not myfont and not mycol
dev.off()
```

Exporting manually via the RStudio plot window works, by the way, but that's not the way to go for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R discriminates between devices when using `par(...)`, which means it must be set *after* `png(...)`.

From **Details** in `?par`:

> Each device has its own set of graphical parameters.

This works:

```
library(extrafont)
loadfonts(device='win')
myfont <- 'Calibri'
mycol <- '#4B4B4D'

# first, open png device
png('d:/working/example.png', units = "in", width = 16, height = 9, pointsize = 12,
    res = 300, family = myfont, type = 'windows')

# Then set plot parameters in par; font and colors
par(family = myfont, fg = mycol, col = mycol, col.axis = mycol, col.lab = mycol, col.main = mycol, col.sub = mycol)

# Initiate plot
plot(x = c(1:10), y = rep(1, 10))
dev.off()
```